# Keep parent menu toggle Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, toggle

Hello I need to keep parent menu open when a corresponding submenu has been selected.

I have the following code for the menu

```js
var $menu = $('#menu'),
  $menu_openers = $menu.children('ul').find('.opener');

// Openers.
$menu_openers.each(function() {

  var $this = $(this);


  $this.on('click', function(event) {

    // Prevent default.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Toggle.
    $menu_openers.not($this).removeClass('active');
    $this.toggleClass('active');

    // Trigger resize (sidebar lock).
    $window.triggerHandler('resize.sidebar-lock');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">

  <ul>

    <li>
      <span class="opener">Submenu</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ipsum Adipiscing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tempus Magna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feugiat Veroeros</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span class="opener">Another Submenu</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ipsum Adipiscing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tempus Magna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feugiat Veroeros</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

How I could achieve to keep it open base on selection?
thank you!

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it ot a [mcve] - you are missing `$window` in the code

Comment: I also strongly suggest you delegate from the top container

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.opener').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
  });
```

```css
#menu ul li ul
{
   display:none;
}
.active{
     display:block !important;
}
.opener{
     cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">

  <ul>

    <li>
      <span class="opener">Submenu</span>
      <ul class="submenu deactive">
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Dolor1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ipsum Adipiscing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tempus Magna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feugiat Veroeros</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span class="opener">Another Submenu</span>
      <ul class="submenu deactive">
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ipsum Adipiscing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tempus Magna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feugiat Veroeros</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```